# Como comparar elementos de mesmo índice em uma lista

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte problema para resolver:

> Considere que Mariazinha tenha realizado um aprova de múltipla escolha. Desejamos, agora, determinar o número de acertos de Mariazinha. Para tal, são fornecidos o gabarito e as respostas em duas linhas consecutivas, ambos na forma de um String de mesmo comprimento. A entrada pode ser dada como abaixo, sendo o resultado um número inteiro correspondente ao número de acertos (5, neste caso):
>
> ```
> abcbdab
> aecbaab
> ```

A minha ideia para solucionar o problema foi criar duas listas distintas, uma contendo as respostas, e outra, o gabarito. Entretanto, não sei como posso comparar o primeiro elemento de uma lista com o primeiro elemento da outra, e somente isso; isto é, após efetuada a comparação, o programa passa para o próximo elemento.
Tentei executar o seguinte código:

```
def numeros_de_acertos(escolhas,gabarito):
    c = 0
    lista_escolhas = list(escolhas)
    lista_gabarito = list(gabarito)
    
    
    for x in lista_escolhas:
        for y in lista_gabarito:
            if x == y:
                c += 1
    return c
```

Entretanto, na estrutura de repetição, ele compara o primeiro elemento com todos os elementos da segunda lista, acrescentando mais acertos ao contador do que deveria.

Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não precisa converter as *strings* para listas. No Python, as *strings* também são iteráveis. A forma mais simples de você fazer essa comparação é criar um `zip` entre as duas *strings* e comparar os valores:

```
escolhas = 'abcbdab'
gabaritos = 'aecbaab'

acertos = 0

for escolha, gabarito in zip(escolhas, gabaritos):
    if escolha == gabarito:
        acertos += 1

print(f'Acertou {acertos} questões')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-384347) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/4By0JZ)</sup>

Porém, se lembrarmos que o tipo booleano no Python é definido como um subtipo de `int`, onde `True` vale 1 e `False` vale 0, podemos apenas fazer a mesma verificação, mas somando diretamente o resultado da condição:

```
for escolha, gabarito in zip(escolhas, gabaritos):
    acertos += (escolha == gabarito)
```

Ou utilizando na forma reduzida, fazendo uso da função `sum`:

```
acertos = sum(escolha == gabarito for escolha, gabarito in zip(escolhas, gabaritos))
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! :) Ainda sou iniciante em python e desconhecia a função ZIP. Dei mais uma pesquisada e consegui entender. Valeu!

Comment: Não sabia dessa que True é o mesmo que 1. Muito bom. +1